# Thrift Server - Scribe Stream Read

Tags: thrift, scribe

I would like to build a thrift server which would feign itself as a Scribe Server and read all the from different boxes and basing on information present in logs, send out alerts or perform certain actions.

Are there any available projects which would suit my requirements ? If I have to write it from scratch how would I read the log lines in server ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrote it from scratch and works fine. Just changed the Python thrift code to listen to scribe's forwarder and process it accordingly. Since both use the same protocol it was not much of a hassle.

Comment: Care to share some code? I'm looking to do the same thing, would rather not reinvent the wheel =)

Comment: This is quite a time later, but do you have any advice on this? I'm currently trying to do something very similar.